# @Required not auto-wiring byName bydefault

Tags: java, spring, autowired, required

I am practicing Spring basics and have understanding that @Required auto-wires bean byName if you do not specify the  for bean.

However, its not working for me. PFB set of classes and configuration file-

Main class:

```
public class DrawingApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        Shape shape = (Shape)ac.getBean("shape");
        shape.draw();
        ac.registerShutdownHook();
    }
}
```

Circle.java:

```
   public class Circle implements Shape {
        Point centre;

        @Override
        public void draw() {
            System.out.println("Drawing Circle");
            System.out.println("Circle centre is (" + centre.getX() + ", " + centre.getY() + ")");
        }

        public Point getCentre() {
            return centre;
        }

        @Required
        public void setCentre(Point centre) {
            this.centre = centre;
        }
}
```

And spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="/src/*"/> -->
    <bean id='triangle' class='org.mayur.spring.Triangle' autowire="byName">
        <property name="type" value="Scalene" />
        <property name="height" value="20" />
        <property name="width" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <bean id='pointA' class='org.mayur.spring.Point' name="pointD,pointE pointF">
        <property name="x" value="0" />
        <property name="y" value="0" />
    </bean>

    <bean id='pointB' class='org.mayur.spring.Point'>
        <property name="x" value="-20" />
        <property name="y" value="0" />
    </bean>

    <bean id='pointC' class='org.mayur.spring.Point'>
        <property name="x" value="0" />
        <property name="y" value="20" />
    </bean>

    <bean id='centre' class='org.mayur.spring.Point'>
        <property name="x" value="-10" />
        <property name="y" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <bean id='shape' class='org.mayur.spring.Circle'>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"></bean>  

</beans>
```

Ideally this set up should inject 'centre' bean into 'shape' bean and it should print circles draw() method.

However, I am getting below exception-

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shape' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Property 'centre' is required for bean 'shape'
```

Please help me with what is wrong here?

Comment: No it doesn't. `@Required` is only for validation it will not auto wire anything. And as there is no bean named `centre` nothing will be injected.

Comment: You can put a breakpoint at "public void setCentre(Point centre)" to see the configuration is correct.

Comment: There is bean with name 'centre' in spring.xml. (Probably you missed a scroll down in spring.xml :)). My understanding is @Required is used for validation+injection

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. `@Required` doesn't do anything for injection, you either need to specify how to do auto wiring in xml on the element or add `@Autowired`.

Comment: Yes, you are right M.Deinum. I confused @Resource with @ Required. @ Resource does auto-wiring byName by default. I changed it to @ Resource and it worked fine. Thank you! This question can be considered closed.